# How to align images inside a thumbnail side by side?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I have four images where the first two images will be side by side and the rest two images will go to the next row. **Currently I have four but there could be more.**

I have used a container two put all the contents inside and each of the images are inside a thumbnail.

I have also added the zoom on scroll effect where on hovering each image, it will zoom and overlap any other image.

But I have trouble putting the images side by side. Here is the screenshot below

[image]

Also if I try other set of images, I get alignment right but it screws up when I hover on the images.

[image]

But this doesn't help. I don't see image getting any bigger with any size value I put.

**Secondly I want a consistent alignment across any number of images** I put where there will always be **two images per row** and hovering on any image doesnt screw the alignment of other images. Adding the below code helps in zoom on hover but **sometimes it messes up the position of other images**.

```
img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.5);
     z-index: 1;
     position: relative;
```

I am using bootstrap for alignment so that the alignment is consistent across any screen size.

How can I make this work?

Here is HTML/CSS snippet

```css
div {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.container .row img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;

    /*object-fit:scale-down;*/
    /*object-fit: contain;*/
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.5);
     z-index: 1;
     position: relative;
     background:rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
     border: 1px solid black;
     opacity: 1;
}
.img{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Summary</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="link.css"
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 style">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://demo.utorlabs.com/static/jsw/balance1543844865.53.svg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 style">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://demo.utorlabs.com/static/jsw/balance1543832720.7.svg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 style">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://demo.utorlabs.com/static/jsw/balance1543833670.32.svg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 style">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://demo.utorlabs.com/static/jsw/latency1543855760.2.svg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using Bootstrap 3, which uses float for columns. This has some issues. Switch to Bootstrap 4 and your problem might be solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your code and just changed Bootstrap version from 3.3.7 to current 4.1.3 and … voilá!

```css
div {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.container .row img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;

    /*object-fit:scale-down;*/
    /*object-fit: contain;*/
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.5);
     z-index: 1;
     position: relative;
     background:rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
     border: 1px solid black;
     opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 style">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://demo.utorlabs.com/static/jsw/balance1543844865.53.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 style">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://demo.utorlabs.com/static/jsw/balance1543832720.7.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 style">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://demo.utorlabs.com/static/jsw/balance1543833670.32.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 style">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://demo.utorlabs.com/static/jsw/latency1543855760.2.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 it is!

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
.style:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

```css
div {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.container .row img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;

    /*object-fit:scale-down;*/
    /*object-fit: contain;*/
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.5); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.5);
     z-index: 1;
     position: relative;
     background:rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
     border: 1px solid black;
     opacity: 1;
}

.style:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 style">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://demo.utorlabs.com/static/jsw/balance1543844865.53.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 style">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://demo.utorlabs.com/static/jsw/balance1543832720.7.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 style">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://demo.utorlabs.com/static/jsw/balance1543833670.32.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 style">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://demo.utorlabs.com/static/jsw/latency1543855760.2.svg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Bootstrap is 12 column grid, you need to set two images in a  with width col-6* classes to align two images.
And provide a "overflow: hidden" for .row since it doesn't break when you hover.
I have added the fiddle for your reference.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tanuj916/xpvt214o/979988/)

```
.row{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```